# SetFocus has no effect in Userform for Textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform, setfocus

I have a UserForm with a textbox for a date. On Exit I want to test if the entered Value is a date and if not a MsgBox pops up, informing about the entry beeing invalid. This works all fine.

But I also want the cursor to be back in the textbox, so people are forced to make a correct entry. I Tried it with `.SetFocus` and `.SelStart = 1`. Both had no effect. After Exiting, the MsgBox pops up but the cursor is not in the box. No error message either. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub tbRGDatum_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

With tbRGDatum
    If IsDate(.Value) Then
        .Text = Format(.Text, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    Else
        MsgBox "Bitte gültiges Datum im Format DD.MM.YYYY eingeben"
        .SetFocus
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

In desperation I also tried to put `tbRGDatum.SetFocus` below `End With` instead of inside, just to test it, but still, nothing happened.

Suspecting the MsgBox to be the culprit, I tried the code without it, to no avail.
Also I tried using `_AfterUpdate` as event handler with the same result.

Looking forward to your suggestions!

Comment: Partially helpful? [Unexpected behaviour after using SetFocus on a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55011102/vba-userform-unexpected-behaviour-after-using-setfocus-on-a-textbox/55030162#55030162)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls. try Cancel set to True in case false data entry. This cancel the Exit event.

```
With tbRGDatum
    If IsDate(.Value) Then
        .Text = Format(.Text, "dd.mm.yyyy")
    Else
        MsgBox "Bitte gültiges Datum im Format DD.MM.YYYY eingeben"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End With

End Sub
```